# Как обновить текущее значение данных посредством JS + PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

Имеется переменная `<?php echo $score['num_score']; ?>` который выводит результат пользователя, но пока не обновишь страницу не можешь посмотреть актуальный результат, как посредством JS организовать актуальность данных, при котором js каждый раз обращается к php перемене и получает актуальный результат, далее показывает его в html с определенным id?

Comment: "Обращается к php переменной" Во время работы javascript не существует никаких php переменных

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```js
function takeNum() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        (async function () {
            const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000");
            res = await res.text();
            document.querySelector(".score").textContent = res;
        }())
        takeNum();
    }, 5000);
}
```

Здесь мы раз в 5 секунд делаем запрос на сервер и выводим полученные данные на страницу.

Comment: По-моему забыли что-то вроде `await res.text()`

Comment: @anreymal, поправил

Comment: А теперь код пишет ошибку синтаксиса)

Comment: @andreymal, переписал функцию